# Getting ERROR 1093 (HY000) using subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| id | pack_id | user_id |     start_date      |       end_date      | runtime |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 1  |    52   |   9     | 2019-04-09 11:53:00 | 2019-04-09 11:54:00 |   60    |
| 2  |    52   |   9     | 2019-04-09 11:58:00 |         NULL        |   NULL  |
```

I would like to update the `end_date` and `runtime` of the last id of the same `pack_id` and `user_id`.
`end_date` have to take the current datetime.
Here is my query :

```
UPDATE 
    myTable 
SET 
    end_date = NOW(),
    runtime = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_date, NOW()) 
WHERE 
    id = (
        SELECT 
            max(id) 
        FROM 
            myTable 
        WHERE 
            user_id = '9' 
        AND 
            pack_id = '52'
    )
```

And I get the following error :

> ERROR 1093 (HY000) at line 1: You can't specify target table
>   'myTable' for update in FROM clause

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in MySQL, so use a `JOIN` instead:

```
UPDATE myTable t JOIN
       (SELECT max(id) as max_id
        FROM myTable 
        WHERE user_id = '9' AND pack_id = '52'
       ) tt
       ON t.id = tt.max_id
    SET t.end_date = NOW(),
        t.runtime = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, t.start_date, NOW()) ;
```

Comment: Why we can't do this in MySQL ? Can we do it in other dbms ?

Comment: @executable . . . It is a MySQL limitation (and so would apply to MariaDB as well).  Your version would work in any other database.

Answer (score 0):

use subquery deeper into a from clause

```
UPDATE 
    myTable 
SET 
    end_date = NOW(),
    runtime = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_date, NOW()) 
WHERE 
    id = (
 select id from (
        SELECT 
            max(id) as id
        FROM 
            myTable 
        WHERE 
            user_id = '9' 
        AND 
            pack_id = '52'
) a
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need  a subquery for create a temp set of value and avoid the use of the same table for updated  and select at same level.
You can do thi using a nested select   eg:

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET  end_date = NOW(),
    runtime = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_date, NOW()) 
WHERE id = (
select  max_id from (
        SELECT 
            max(id)  max_id  
        FROM  myTable 
        WHERE  user_id = '9' 
        AND pack_id = '52'

        ) t   )
```

or an inner join on the subquery

```
UPDATE myTable m 
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT 
            max(id)  max_id  
        FROM  myTable 
        WHERE  user_id = '9' 
        AND pack_id = '52'

        ) t   ON t.max_id  =  m.id 

SET  end_date = NOW(),
    runtime = TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_date, NOW())
```